Curl request succeeded but JavaScript fetch failed
I have two AWS EC2 instance, one for JavaScript web page and one for Django server.
Django server is in private subnet and JavaScript in public subnet.
My JavaScript fetch code is like below
fetch('http://10.0.136.201:8080/evaluation/get-price/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = String(Math.round(Number(JSON.stringify(data['answer'])))) + "원";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('오류가 발생했습니다. 다시 시도해주세요.');
    });


And my curl command is this
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key": "value"}' http://10.0.136.201:8080/evaluation/get-price/

I can see the curl request from Django server log and it return response successfully, but when I use fetch in JavaScript, even there is no any log that JavaScript requested.
Is there any problem with browser? I assume there is no problem with AWS security group, because curl command works well.

That curl request is to a private IP address, so that command would only work from within the VPC. Your JavaScript web application doesn't actually run on a server in your VPC, it runs in the web browser of the user viewing your webpage. The server that is serving up the JavaScript webapp is just serving up raw files to the web browser, the code is actually executed on the web browser.
The computer the JavaScript is actually running on, (the user's laptop/desktop PC) is not in the VPC, and does not have a network route to the private Django server.
You will have to expose your API/Django server to the Internet somehow, either by making it public, or by placing something like API Gateway in front of it, or by configuring the server that serves the JavaScript code to also proxy API requests to the Django server.
